# Why is HorizontalScrollView not working (Android)?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I don't understand why the horizontal scrollview is not working, the vertical scroll view works fine, can someone clarify me? I searched online for answers but nothing seems to work, I already tried nested scrollview and listview. My Idea is to create a quiz, organized in a vertical linear layout, but some of the questions have multiple checkbox answers, and it does not fit the width of the screen so I tried to add a horizontal scrollview so I can access all of the check boxes without them being badly formatted.

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.co... 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/ap... 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/... 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context="com.example.android.quiz.... 

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"> 

<Textview> </TextView> 

<HorizontalScrollView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"~ 
android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"> 

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal"> 

<CheckBox><CheckBox/> 

<LinearLayout/> 

<HorizontalScrollView/> 

<LinearLayout/> 

<Scrollview/>
```

Comment: Putting `Scrollable` content within `scrollable` is not good practice.

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Comment: Avoid these kind of situations. If you do, you have to manage `TouchEvent` manually. Alternatives are use `recyclerview` with multiple items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add recycler view to your layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

In java file set its orientation to horizontal

```
LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
LayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
```